# OO design for logging

Tags: oop

I am developing an application in which one part is a logging mechanism. I have defined a business logic when in every setter of each class an event is raised with the reference to the object that was changed and old value of the changed attribute. I have created a class called `Logger` that listens to that events and creates a log.

But, I don't want to have a event handler for each of the events. I would like the `Logger` to catch events, which parameters is an interface, let's call it 'Logging'. So from `Logger's` point of view, the logging would be unified.

The question is, how to use this `Logging` interface. I don't want my business classes to implement it. Could you give me some ideas what would be the best approach to do this in a nice OO design?

Thank you.

Comment: Which language are you using

Comment: You can try Aspect-oriented programming. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555969/traditional-logging-vs-aop-logging

Comment: Singleton design pattern is perfect for a logger